# Scattering parameter oscillation

Tags: experimental-physics, microwaves

Why does scattering parameter $S_{11}$ for a two port measurement with a simple cable oscillate with frequency?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem..

And it's gone when I terminate the port impedance with resistance same as the characteristic impedance of the circuit.
I think this happens because unless the impedance is matched, it acts as a resonator either both ends closed or opened...

Have you solved your problem? If yes, can we discuss the reason why it oscillates?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/392229)